# Sum a list of arrays

Tags: arrays, r, list

I have a large list of arrays of the same dimension:

```
a<-array(NA,dim=c(2,4,3))
b<-array(NA,dim=c(2,4,3))
c<-array(NA,dim=c(2,4,3))

list<-list(a,b,c)
```

I would like to sum over all the arrays to produce a single array which is the sum of all in the list.

So basically: `a+b+c`

Is there a way to do this?

I know it can be done with matrices but I haven't been able to find a function for arrays.

Comment: Please replace the NA values with actual values and show the answer you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce("+", list)
```