# Variance of a List of Arrays

Tags: r

Suppose `x` is a list of arrays.

```
a <- array(1,c(2,3,4));
b <- array(2,c(2,3,4));
c <- array(3,c(2,3,4));

x <- list(a=a,b=b,c=c)
```

My desired output is the following array:

```
   array(var(c(1,2,3)),c(2,3,4))
```

This is quietly same as the following page, but change the sum to the variance.

Ref: [Sum a list of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008812/sum-a-list-of-arrays)

---

Edit for comments of @akrun

Thank you @akrun.
His answer is the following;

```
    apply(
     array(unlist(x),append( dim(x[[1]]), length(x) )  ),
     1:length(dim(x[[1]])),
     var
)
```

where `x` is the following list of arrays:

```
a <- array(1,c(2,3,4));
b <- array(2,c(2,3,4));
c <- array(3,c(2,3,4));
d <- array(4,c(2,3,4));
x <- list(a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d)
```

Comment: Sorry !!  I add the example. If there is simple or faster code exists, please let me know !! I am sorry, Cafe will be close, I can reply at least one day later.

Comment: You may need `apply(array(unlist(x), c(2, 3, 4, 3)), 1:3, var)`

Comment: Thank you for @akrun, but I have not a time, I try your code tomorrow !! thank you for reply !!

Comment: Oh !! I forget to say thank you for @NelsonGon he edit my english to nice one yesterday. My English is poor, so such edition helps me very much !! Thank YOU !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to `unlist` the `list`, create an `array` and use `apply` to get the `var`iance

```
apply(array(unlist(x), c(2, 3, 4, 3)), 1:3, var)
```

Comment: Thank YOU !! The code goes well !! It helps me very much, since the function in your codes belong to the package base only !! I write the dependency of `x` more explicitly as above.